# How to create a modular .NET Core MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-mac, .net-core-3.0

Some of the requirements are:

- Centralize reusable functionality in the main application ("main")
- Load/unload modules into the main application and use main features in those modules. E.g., In **main** we have a database connection, so the **A**, **B**, … modules are capable of using this database.
- Each module can have its own models, controllers, and views. Also, it may have its own files such as styles, scripts, or assets (images, fonts, or something).

I have doubts at:

- How can I achieve this modular structure?
- How can files (scripts, images, etc.) from this modules be loaded into the main application?
- Can the modules have their own layouts?
- Can using `@section` help with adding module styles, scripts?
- Can Vue be used at in the main application, and used by the modules?

I'm asking this because couldn't find any "updated" answer. I'm using .NET Core 3.0 on Visual Studio for Mac.

Comment: My approach would be to use dependency injection, and define the DI registration class in Web.config so you can swap out the physical implementation of each interface at will.

Comment: @fernando-lopez: Welcome to StackOverlow! This is a pretty broad question, and quickly gets into a pretty open-ended design questions which may not yield good answers. That said, it's certainly an _interesting_ question and a fun challenge.

Comment: If I use DI then its more manual job, is there anyway to compile this module into some DLL and place it in some directory at core app, then this application loads all DLLs from this folder?

Comment: @FernandoLopez: There are ways to do this, though it can get pretty complicated. The basic strategy is to define an interface for configuring each module, implement a class in each module which implements that interface, and then use reflection to find all classes which implement that interface in your startup class, and execute a configuration method. There are frameworks, such as **Managed Extensibility Framework** (now part of `Microsoft.Composition`) which can aid in this process. But there are a lot of caveats and challenges that you'll inevitably run into.

Comment: @FernandoLopez: It's worth noting that if each of your modules are simply defining an MVC application _and_ you're using a _dependency injection container_ (such as the one built into **ASP.NET Core**) for relaying service implementations from your main application, then you _may_ be able to get away with using MVC to discover your modules, depending on how your routes are configured, since it has built-in functionality for locating and registering controllers.

Comment: Hey @FernandoLopez—wanted to check in and see if this helped give you the direction you needed, or if you had any additional questions.

Comment: I have been playing arround with dll loading guess its called "reflection". Will come with more doubts later, thanks for your awnser.

Comment: @FernandoLopez: Yeah, you’ll almost certainly need to use reflection for dynamically loading the assemblies and identifying your module configuration methods. If my answer does end up helping, please do mark it as the answer. Regardless, though, good luck on your project!

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different approaches and strategies for solving these types of problems, depending on your exact requirements. In fact, there are entire frameworks that have been written to aid with packaging, registering, and embedding plugin into .NET (see e.g. **Managed Extensibility Framework**).

That said, I can help point you in a direction that might help you work through these issues.

#### Distributing MVC apps as modules

First and foremost, I'd look into **Razor Class Libraries**. These were introduced in **ASP.NET Core 2.1** and expanded in **ASP.NET Core 3.0**. They allow you to create a assembly that contains models, views, and controllers (in **ASP.NET Core 2.1**) as well as static assets (e.g., scripts, images, &c.) (in **ASP.NET Core 3.0**). These can even be packaged and redistributed as **NuGet** packages, if you need to distribute these for use on multiple projects.

> *Note:* Technically, if you need, there are ways to embed static assets in **ASP.NET Core 2.1** Razor Class Libraries, but it's not enabled by default, has some limitations, and the format has changed in **ASP.NET Core 3.0**.

#### Referencing shared static content from modules

Your **Razor Class Libraries** can call any static resources or views from your main application—though this isn't really a best practice, since it means establishing hard-coded dependencies on resources outside of a particular project, which makes it difficult to change where those files are, or test if they are even pointing to the correct location. A better option might be to register (the location of) those resources with a *configuration object* and use that object to reference those location.

#### Referencing shared class libraries from within modules

Regardless, by default, your **Razor Class Libraries** won't be able to call into classes that are contained in your main application. The way around this is to use *dependency injection*, as @jonny-lin recommends in the comments. The basic idea here is that you establish a central class library which both your **Razor Class Libraries** and your main application depend on which defines interfaces for each service. Your main application (or its dependencies) establish concrete versions of those services. Your modules, in turn, depend on those interfaces. You can then *inject* the concrete implementation of those services into your modules.

> *Note:* There are a number of strategies for implementing dependency injection, from manually assembling your dependency graph via an `IControllerActivator` to using a *dependency injection container*, such as the one built into **ASP.NET Core**. Regardless, in an MVC application, the general strategy is to have the controller accept required interfaces via the constructor, and then to inject concrete implementations via the main application.

#### Configuring modules in your main application

Finally, you need to establish a way to register your modules with your main application. If it just defines reusable class libraries, this may be as simple as referencing the assembly and then calling its classes. If it contains a basic MVC application, it may already be available, depending on how you're handling your routing—but, in many cases, you'll need to setup a new route for an area. In a more complex scenario, it will likely make sense to create extension methods in your modules that can be called from your `Startup` class in order to handle the registration of services and routes.

#### *Automatically* discovering modules in your main application

Of course, if you want the modules to be *automatically* detected and configured by the main application, this gets a bit more tricky. In that case, you'll likely end up establishing a configuration class in each module that implements a predetermined interface—e.g., `IModuleConfiguration`. Your main application will then use reflection to find all classes in all loaded assemblies that implement `IModuleConfiguration` and call a configuration method on each one. That method will almost certainly need to have some form of dependency injection so that dependencies each module relies upon can be registered as part of the configuration. One library that can help with features like this is `Microsoft.Composition`, which is a partial port of the **Managed Extensibility Framework** to ASP.NET Core. This can get pretty complicated pretty quickly, though.

Obviously, actually implementing all of this is potentially very involved, and will almost certainly invite plenty of additional questions, depending on how familiar you are with these approaches. My goal in this answer isn't to address all of those eventualities, but to lay out the general strategy for approaching this type of problem.

Hope this helps!

Comment: FWIW: Here’s an implementation of an [embeddable **Razor Class Library**](https://github.com/OnTopicCMS/OnTopic-Library/tree/master/OnTopic.AspNetCore.Mvc) that I wrote. It incorporates dependency injection and a couple of extension methods for registering the application, its routes, and its dependencies. Here’s [another **Razor Class Library**](https://github.com/OnTopicCMS/OnTopic-Editor-AspNetCore) I contributed to which includes static content, some of which is downloaded via **npm** and built using **Gulp**. That said, neither demonstrate automatic detection of modules.

Comment: Also, here’s a [really simple example of using reflection to discover classes in loaded assemblies](https://github.com/OnTopicCMS/OnTopic-Library/blob/master/OnTopic/Reflection/DynamicTypeLookupService.cs). It isn’t looking for a specific interface, nor using them for automatic configuration, but neither of those are especially difficult to add. (It’s combining extension methods with dependency injection where things get a bit more involved, since most dependency injection containers aren’t well-suited for dynamically injecting dependencies into static methods.)